# How to create a map chart with direction arrows in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking at creating a few maps like this on the [eia website site](http://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.cfm?id=20592#tabs_Slider-5).

Would you be able to point me to direction in creating a map like this? Or is R not able to create such a chart?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the map you can check out the maps package. The maps function in the map package lets you create maps quite easily by just naming a region name, like "world" or "usa", or you can set coordinates

For the arrows you can try out the arrows() command. You can set the coordinates of where the arrow starts and ends as well as set the line width.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the suggestions of @CactusWoman

```
library(maps)
library(igraph)
map("usa")
map.axes()
igraph:::igraph.Arrows(-120, 40, -90, 45, curve=0.3, sh.col="blue")
igraph:::igraph.Arrows(-100, 35, -110, 38, curve=0.5, sh.lwd=5, sh.col="orange")
```

Additional write-up on `igraph:::igraph.Arrows` available [here](https://kbroman.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/curved-arrows-in-r/)

[image: Arrow Map]